# How to know the field is dependent and get dependent values in Netsuite suitscript 2.0?

Tags: netsuite, suitescript

I can able to get all fields and options if it is select.
Below is code,

```
var objectRecord = record.create({
              type: context.resourceType,
              isDynamic: true
            });
            var fields = objectRecord.getFields();
            var allFields = [];
            fields.forEach(function(fieldName) {
                var field = objectRecord.getField({ fieldId: fieldName});
                    var fieldDetail = {
                        name : field.id,
                        label : field.label,
                        type : field.type,
                        required : field.isMandatory,
                        options : (field.getSelectOptions ? field.getSelectOptions() : [])
                    };
                    allFields.push(fieldDetail);
            });
```

But some of the fields are dependent fields.

1. By clicking check box, some fields are enabled to edit
2. By selecting value of one select box, the child select values are showing (Values are depending on other select box)

How do we know in suitescript 2.0 that these fields are

- controlling(parent) fields
- dependent fields
- dependent values if field is dependent

Comment: Did you find the solution for this? Can you please share the solution. I am facing the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Reached Netsuite support team and got reply on Apr 16, 2019. Getting dependency option is not implemented in Netsuite yet using Suitescript 2.0. 
So I am using Netsuite 1.0 script to get dependent fields.